# Is there way to remove margin pdf reports using html string?

Tags: c#, html, css

I have tried make a pdf reports using dinktopdf, but the problem is i cannot remove the margins pdf. I already try body margin 0, but it's awkward way.

Anyone can tell me, how to remove margin pdf using dinktopdf?

here my output :

[image]

**noted : redline is the margin**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf#convert) you should be able to control the margins in the GlobalSettings object.

```
var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
{
    GlobalSettings = {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        Margins = new MarginSettings() { Top = 10 },
        Out = @"C:\DinkToPdf\src\DinkToPdf.TestThreadSafe\test.pdf",
    },
...
};
```

After having a look in the [source code](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/blob/master/src/DinkToPdf/Settings/MarginSettings.cs) I guess that the following should work.

```
Margins = new MarginSettings() { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
```